# Twilio Threaded Messages

Tags: java, multithreading, twilio

If I want to kick off a thread that will be sending a text message with twilio,
is it better to do

```
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
```

for each thread or should I make one client and share it with the threads?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the source code for TwilioRequestClient class of the [twilio-java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) helper library here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/sdk/TwilioRestClient.java

I don't see anything not obviously thread-safe. My only concern would be this part of the code in the constructor:

```
//Grab the proper connection manager, based on runtime environment
ClientConnectionManager mgr = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest");
    mgr = new AppEngineClientConnectionManager();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    //Not GAE
    mgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager();
    ((ThreadSafeClientConnManager) mgr).setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
}
```

It generates a new thread pool for every initialization, so I'd say share the resource. On the other hand, will it have enough connections available to efficiently handle your load?

You can read up more about ThreadSafeClientConnManager here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html#setDefaultMaxPerRoute%28int%29

Bottom line, try load testing it with your expected usage and tweak the source to meet your needs.